# Как включить расширения в конфиг TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

Я хочу чтобы когда я запускал tsc мне в dist собирался проект и заменял все: **import module from "./modules/module"** на **import module from "./modules/module.js"**

Comment: Насколько я помню TS такими вещами не занимается. Это нужно править через бандлер, либо через конфиг фреймворка/библиотеки, который вы используете. Можете предоставить больше контекста? Проект полностью сами писали или использовали фреймворки?

Comment: Полностью сам, но проблема уже не актуальна, возможно кому-то ваш ответ был полезен, спасибо.